# PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid. When adding <tr> tag in VF page

Tags: visualforce, error

I have a VF page as PDF. I have added `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` for all the section. When I am running the page it is throwing error:

> PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid.

But once I am removing  tag from some section not all it is running fine. But same VF not running for other record, same error is coming.

for below code I am not getting error if I am adding `<tr>`

```
<tr>
  <apex:repeat value="{!mapOfFieldName}" var="mapKey">
    <apex:variable value="" var="v" rendered="{!IF( mapKey =='Natio',true,false)}">
        <apex:variable value="" var="p" rendered="{!mapOfFieldName[mapKey].Display_on__c}">
          <td width="50%"><b>First Name:</b> {!objLead.Name}</td>
        </apex:variable>
      </apex:variable>
   </apex:repeat>

  <apex:repeat value="{!mapOfFieldName}" var="mapKey">
    <apex:variable value="" var="v" rendered="{!IF( mapKey =='Name',true,false)}">
      <apex:variable value="" var="p" rendered="{!mapOfFieldName[mapKey].Display_on__C}">
        <td width="50%"><b> First Name 2:</b>{!objLead.Name2__c}</td> 
      </apex:variable>
    </apex:variable>
  </apex:repeat>
 </tr>
```

But for below code I am getting error if adding . If I don't add alignment is not correct.

```
<tr>
  <apex:repeat value="{!mapOfFieldName}" var="mapKey">
    <apex:variable value="" var="v" rendered="{!IF( mapKey =='Physics_marks_c' && objLead.Physics_marks_c!=null,true,false)}">
      <apex:variable value="" var="p" rendered="{!mapOfFieldName[mapKey].Display_on__c}">
        <td width="50%"><b>{!mapOfFieldName[mapKey].Field_Label__c}:</b>{!objLead.Physics_marks__c}</td>
      </apex:variable>
    </apex:variable> 
  </apex:repeat> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML structure is quite strict when rendering page as PDF, you seem to be skipping `TD`'s conditionally; thus making the generated HTML in PDF invalid.

Make content inside `TD` conditional and use a blank space with `&nbsp;` in case content is empty.

Use of apex:variable here is not proper, you could rewrite the condition as:

```
<tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!mapOfFieldName}" var="mapKey">
            <td width="50%">
                <apex:variable var="condition" value="{!mapKey =='Physics_marks_c' && objLead.Physics_marks_c!=null && 
                    mapOfFieldName[mapKey].Display_on__c}"/>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!condition}" layout="none">
                    <b>{!mapOfFieldName[mapKey].Field_Label__c}:</b>{!objLead.Physics_marks__c}
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(condition)}" layout="none">
                    &nbsp;
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </td>
    </apex:repeat> 
</tr>
```